# iphone sqlite3 object allocation memory up but no leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, object, sqlite, allocation

i've been trying to figure out wh. sqy my object allocation keeps rigth up  every time i call this function, Instruments reports no leaks but I get a heck of a lot of object coming from

```
sqlite3_exec --> sqlite3Prepare --> sqlite3Parser --> yy_reduce --> malloc  & also a whole bunch from 

& from

sqlite3Step --> sqlite3VdbeExec --> sqlite3BtreeInsert --> malloc
```

I tried solving it by following the suggestions posted here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7092-sqlite3-database-gobbling-up-memory.html but haven't been able to fix it

ANY HELP is appreciated, my code is below

```
+(void)getDesignationsInLibrary:(NSString *)library
{
NSAutoreleasePool *localPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
NSString *dbName = @"s8.sqlite";



NSArray *documentPaths = \
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains \
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = \
[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = \
[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

[[DT sharedDT].designationsInLibrary removeAllObjects];

NSString *sqlString;

for(int i=0;i<[[DT sharedDT].typesInLibrary count];i++)
{   

 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
 {
     if (sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to set cache size with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
     }
     NSMutableString *lib=[NSMutableString stringWithString:library];

     [lib appendString:@"-"];
     [lib appendString:[[DT sharedDT].typesInLibrary objectAtIndex:i]];

     if([DT sharedDT].sortedBy==@"AISC Default")
     {
         sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select DESIGNATION from \"%@\";",lib];
     }
     else
     {
         sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select DESIGNATION from \"%@\" order by cast(%@ as numeric) %@;",lib, [DT sharedDT].sortedBy, [DT sharedDT].sortAscDesc]; 
     }

     const char *sql = [sqlString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql,-1,&selectstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
     {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                [[DT sharedDT].designationsInLibrary addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)]];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
         selectstmt=nil;
     }
 }

}   
sqlite3_close(db);
[localPool release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that you're opening db on every loop cycle, but close only once, before function exit

So try to change:

```
    }   
sqlite3_close(db);
[localPool release];
}
```

to

```
 
       sqlite3_close(db);
   }   

[localPool release];
}
```

Or even better change:

```
for(int i=0;i [[DT sharedDT].typesInLibrary count];i++)
{   

 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
 {
     if (sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to set cache size with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
     }
```

to:

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to set cache size with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));     
    }

    for(int i=0;i [[DT sharedDT].typesInLibrary count];i++)
    {   
    ...
```

because you're always open the same database

Comment: Agreed. Opening the database on every single loop pass is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking sqlite3_exec with:

```
pragma cache_size=1
```

Sqlite seems to gobble up memory for caching.

Comment: I agree, saw this behavior in my app too. sqlite takes up a lot of memory for caching. Closing the database and opening it again in didReceiveMemoryWarning seems to work though